# How to extract only polygons from Overpass Turbo?

Tags: overpass-api

The query below extracts Polygons and Points:

```
[out:json];
area["name:fr"="Bruxelles-Capitale"]["admin_level"=4]->.a;
rel["admin_level"=8](area.a);
out geom;
```

How do I filter out Points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 1: Simply hide it:

```
[out:json];
area["name:fr"="Bruxelles-Capitale"]["admin_level"=4]->.a;
rel["admin_level"=8](area.a);
out geom;

{{style:
  node {
    width: 0;
    opacity:0;
    fill-opacity:0;  
  }
}}
```

http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/98F

Option 2: Only extract ways from relation:

**Don't forget to enable the flag "Don't display small features as POIs." in Settings -> Map.**

```
[out:json];
area["name:fr"="Bruxelles-Capitale"]["admin_level"=4]->.a;
rel["admin_level"=8](area.a);
out meta;
way(r);
out geom;
```

http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/98H

Comment: Option 2 sounds like the solution, but I must admit I don't understand how this works.  Thanks anyway, though.

Comment: Regarding Option 2: `rel[".."](area.a); out meta;` will just output the relation with some references to its members (but without the members themselves). `way(r)` returns all ways included in the relation (see http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#Recurse_.28n.2C_w.2C_r.2C_bn.2C_bw.2C_br.29), and `out geom;` finally prints the ways along with its nodes. This way, we deliberately didn't print any nodes, which are assigned to the relation as a member only.